# What are the missing items of this number sequence?

Tags: logical-deduction, pattern, number-sequence

1, 2, 5, 13, ?, ?, 1
Please give explanation.

Comment: Is there one and only one answer to this question?

Comment: At first it looks like every odd-numbered Fibonacci, but the 1 at the end throws that off

Comment: @SeraphCheng any finite collection of numbers has an infinite amount of functions that go through all points, as such questions like these NEVER have only one answer. Some however, have very obvious answers.

Answer (score 1):

I would figure that it is simply

> 1,2,5,13,**5**,**2**,1